# How to implement automatic horizontal scrolling for EditText when text size exceeds the size of window?

Tags: android

I am using an EditText in which text is filled programatically by inserting text in another EditText and for that EdiText(Programatically filled), focusable property is set to false. I want the such scenario when the text has filled the complete window and I enter next letter then it should scroll towards left by one letter and same for more letters.

Comment: try setting this to your `edittext in xml android:singleLine="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
  EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTex1);
    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        et2.setText(s);
        et2.setSelection(s.length());
      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
    });
```